# Print what a top level require statement returns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my class, I have the following statement:

```
const MyClass = require('react-native').MyClass;
```

I have this because I am mocking `react-native` for testing purposes.

However, this fails with the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'MyClass' of undefined
```

So I am trying to figure out what actually is imported by placing this `console.log` just before the `require` statement.

```
console.log("In MyTestedClass, 'react-native': " + JSON.stringify(require('react-native')));
const MyClass = require('react-native').MyClass;
```

However, the `console.log` is ignored, probably because it's not in a class.

So how can I print what`require('react-native')` returns?

Where can I put a `console.log` statement?

Comment: console.log should not be ignored if you run the code through node. (maybe it is when you run through a test-runner). try running it directly through node.

Comment: I can't use `node` because I have a custom build system. I can only run the tests thorough `jest`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to require the name of the file containing `MyClass`. This line in your code...

```
const MyClass = require('react-native').MyClass;
```

...is telling the compiler to look in a file named `react-native.js` for a class named `MyClass`.